# Ordinal 3: 3rd vs 3d

Tags: ordinal-numbers

What is the most correct form for *3* in ordinal form: *3rd* or *3d*?
I know both are valid. But I heard that *3rd* is something like spoken form and it's grammatically correct to use *3d*.

Comment: I prefer *3rd*, but I have seen *3d* for this.  Perhaps more commonly in 19th century writing.

Comment: Just interesting, what the reason of down votes? It's a correct question about usage and grammar...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's normal to represent *third* as **3rd**, not "3d". The latter might be used if a foreign language were being translated by someone who is used to using only a single character to represent an ordinal (for example, in Italian).

This is supported by a [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=3rd%2C3d&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) comparing *3rd* to *3d*. The former occurs more often, even though "3d" could have a meaning as "three-dimensional". The large number of occurrences from the nineteenth century are probably explained by "3d" being "three pence", a currency amount so common that it had [its own coin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threepence_%28British_coin%29) from around 1550 to 1967.

Comment: Note that the *rd* part is oft written as a superscript.

Comment: The interesting fact we can notice from Google Ngram is that 3d was more popular in American English and 3rd - in British English.

Answer (score 6):

To be argumentative about the earlier centuries I googled "1st 2d and 3d" ...

A map from 1863, titled:

> Gettysburg Battlefield. Battle fought at Gettysburg, Pa. July 1st, 2d & 3d 1863 by the Federal and Confederate armies commanded respectively by Genl. G. G. Meade and Genl. Robert E. Lee.

[LINK](http://www.loc.gov/item/gm70005048)

volume in the Library of Congress

> Jayne's index register, (1st, 2d and 3d editions) to advertisements (1872)

[LINK](http://archive.org/details/jaynesindexregis00jayn)

and many more...

Comment: Good findings, but what about modern grammar?

Comment: Less common, but not nonexistent.  Job posting from Jaunary, 2013: "Job: Warehouse General Laborer 1st 2d And 3d Shifts"